# Unable to traverse on dom after using javascript map?

Tags: jquery, html

In that i want to get the data table individual cell values by traversing on dom .

Java script code :-

```
$('.table tbody').on('click', 'span.glyphicon-ok', function() {
    var ruleNo=$("#serviceRules option:selected").val();
    var ruleName=$("#serviceRules option:selected").text();
    var studioName=$("#studioView").val();
    activePanel=$('div#afterSelect').find('div.in').attr('id');
    editedRow=$(this).parent().siblings('td.slNo').text();

    $(this).parent().siblings().attr('contenteditable','false').removeAttr('style');
    $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-pencil');
    $.map(configurationObject[studioName], function(value, key){
        if(key != "isp" && key != "country" && key != "studiodefault"){
    if(activePanel=='collapseOne'){
        var ruleType = {
                UserName : $(this).parent().siblings('td').eq(2).text(),
                siteChennal : $(this).parent().siblings('td').eq(3).text(),
            }
            }
    }
});
});
```

HTML doc:-

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>SiteName</th>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Channel</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
              <tr>
              <td class="slNo">1</td>
              <td>www.5plus5.gov.mt</td>
              <td>user2</td><td>channel2</td>
              <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash view-trash">
    </span></td></tr>
</table>
```

JSFiddle link :- http://jsfiddle.net/Murugesan/s0y76oqd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function passed to map context has changed. You can assign "this" to another variable before entering into function.

```
var self = this;
$.map(configurationObject[studioName], function(value, key){
        if(key != "isp" && key != "country" && key != "studiodefault"){
    if(activePanel=='collapseOne'){
        var ruleType = {
                UserName : $(self).parent().siblings('td').eq(2).text(),
                siteChennal : $(self).parent().siblings('td').eq(3).text(),
            }
            }
    }
```